# How to read a C++ SAFEARRAY** that is a Result from a COM interop where the C# return value was byte[]?

Tags: c#, c++, com, byte, interop

I have created a C# DLL that uses a Zebra Crossing Nuget package (ZXing.Net.Bindings.CoreCompat.System.Drawing) that creates a QR image.

The signature of the C# method is:

```
public interface IWriter
{
    byte[] CreateQrCode(string content, int width, int height, string imageFormat);
};
```

and I have successfully used it in a C# Console application to create a variety of QR codes, in which I write the `byte[]` return value to disk as png image files.

Naturally, so that I could call it from C++, I checked the 'Register for COM interop' checkbox on the library's Properties/Build screen, signed the assembly with a strong file name key (without password), and created the following C++ application as a Proof of Concept that demonstrates how to use it:

```
#include <iostream>

#import "C:\Users\[PATH TO C# BUILD]\ImageGenerator\bin\Debug\ImageGenerator.tlb" raw_interfaces_only

using namespace ImageGenerator;

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    IWriterPtr pICalc(__uuidof(Writer));

    BSTR content = SysAllocString(L"http://www.google.com/");
    BSTR format = SysAllocString(L"png");

    const LONG width = 100;
    const LONG height = 100;

    const LONG count = width * height;

    SAFEARRAY** myArray = NULL;

    pICalc->CreateQrCode(content, width, height, format, myArray);
}
```

How do I read the Result of `myArray`, to save it as a file to disk?

The length of the C# `byte[]` array would be `count`.

The C# library code is as follows:

```
using System;
using ZXing;
using System.Drawing;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using ZXing.CoreCompat.System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using BarcodeReader = ZXing.CoreCompat.System.Drawing.BarcodeReader;

namespace ImageGenerator
{

    public interface IWriter
    {
        byte[] CreateQrCode(string content, int width, int height, string imageFormat);
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// An Image Writer class that creates QR code images in a variety of image formats.
    /// </summary>
    public class Writer : IWriter
    {
        public Writer()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a QR Code in a specified image format, of width and height, returning it as byte[].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="content">The content that is to be represented by the QR Code.</param>
        /// <param name="width">The width of the image.</param>
        /// <param name="height">The Height of the image.</param>
        /// <param name="imageFormat">A text string representing the format of the image, options are png, bmp, emf, exif, gif, icon, jpeg, memorybmp, tiff, and wmf.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public byte[] CreateQrCode(string content, int width, int height, string imageFormat)
        {
            ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Png;

            switch(imageFormat.ToLower())
            {
                case "png":
                    format = ImageFormat.Png;
                    break;

                case "bmp":
                    format = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                    break;

                case "emf":
                    format = ImageFormat.Emf;
                    break;

                case "exif":
                    format = ImageFormat.Exif;
                    break;

                case "gif":
                    format = ImageFormat.Gif;
                    break;

                case "icon":
                    format = ImageFormat.Icon;
                    break;

                case "jpeg":
                    format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;

                case "memorybmp":
                    format = ImageFormat.MemoryBmp;
                    break;

                case "tiff":
                    format = ImageFormat.Tiff;
                    break;

                case "wmf":
                    format = ImageFormat.Wmf;
                    break;
            }

            BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
            {
                Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
                {
                    Width = width,
                    Height = height,
                }
            };

            var qrCodeImage = writer.Write(content); // BOOM!!

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                qrCodeImage.Save(stream, format);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `SafeArrayAccessData` to get a prointer of the data retunred. Check the type, should be `VT_BYTE`.

You get the size (dimensions) `SafeArrayGetDim`, `SafeArrayGetLBound`, `SafeArrayGetUBound`

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there are two major problems here:

1. You can't use ZXing.Net.Bindings.CoreCompat.System.Drawing in a COM interop scenario because the CoreCompat.System.Drawing V2 assembly for .Net Standard 2.0 isn't signed. If you check the HRESULT return value of the call pICalc->CreateQrCode(...) you will see the value 0x80131044. If you really want to use CoreCompat.System.Drawing you have to sign it with your own key and build a new version of ZXing.Net.Bindings.CoreCompat.System.Drawing against your version of CoreCompat.System.Drawing. Alternatively, you can target your assembly against .Net Standard 1.3 because the older version CoreCompat.System.Drawing V1 is signed. But I didn't try it. In my case, I checked your code directly against ZXing.Net with the full framework 4.6.1 and the bitmap functionality of the native framework.
2. I had to modify your code in the following way:

   ```
   ...
       SAFEARRAY* myArray = NULL;

       pICalc->CreateQrCode(content, width, height, format, &myArray);
   }
   ```

   That's the way how a pointer to a pointer is used in that case.